# Какая библиотека в Python может взаимодействовать с классами HTML

Tags: python

Я хочу обратиться к определённому классу на сайте ВК-сделать перебор паролей(мне просто для практики), с помощью какой библиотеки можно реализовать(requests вроде неподходит)

Comment: Перебор паролей просто для практики? Лучше попрактикуйтесь на чём-нибудь менее сомнительном с точки зрения уголовного кодекса.

Comment: Я буду ломать только свою страницу, и мне всё равно нужна библиотека или способ взаимодействовать с классами в HTML

Comment: Посмотрите связку (requests + BeautifulSoup) или selenium

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но Beautiful Soup это же парсинг